# Entender algoritmo de PRIM

Tags: python, algoritmos, pseudocódigo

Tengo que implementar el algoritmo de PRIM y no puedo llegar a una solución optima. Por ahora he llegado a una solución por fuerza bruta que funciona, pero funciona en O(V^3) siendo V la cantidad de vértices del grafo. Me estuve fijando en el pseudocódigo de "Introductions to algorithms" de Cormen, pero no entiendo el proceso que realiza, especialmente en "Q".

> In order to implement Prim’s algorithm efficiently, we need a fast way to select
> a new edge to add to the tree formed by the edges in A. In the pseudocode below,
> the connected graph G and the root r of the minimum spanning tree to be grown
> are inputs to the algorithm. During execution of the algorithm, all vertices that
> are not in the tree reside in a min-priority queue Q based on a key attribute. For
> each vertex , the attribute :key is the minimum weight of any edge connecting
> to a vertex in the tree; by convention, :key D 1 if there is no such edge. The
> attribute : names the parent of  in the tree. The algorithm implicitly maintains
> the set A from GENERIC-MST as
> A D f.; :/ W  2 V  frg  Qg :
> When the algorithm terminates, the min-priority queue Q is empty; the minimum
> spanning tree A for G is thus
> A D f.; :/ W  2 V  frgg :

```
 MST-PRIM(G, w, r)

 for each u in G:V

       u:key ← ∞

       u:π ← NIL

   r:key ← 0

   Q ← G:V

   while Q ≠ ∅

       u ← EXTRACT-MIN(Q)

       for each v in G:Adj[u]

           if v ∈ Q and w(u, v) < v:key

              v:π ← u

              v:key ← w(u, v)
```

Alguien me podría ayudar a entenderlo por favor?